# How would I write a jQuery selector to grab the child <input> of $(this)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I tried:

```
$(this).nextAll("input").get(0)
```

Not only does it not work, it looks like it would be overkill if it did.

Comment: Can someone please explain why this simple question of mine was downvoted? It was good enough to get two answers, 9 upvotes on those answers, and a favorite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//child
$(this).children('input');

//descendant
$(this).find('input');
$('input', this);
```

By the way, `.nextAll` is for siblings.

Answer (score 3):

Use simply this :

```
$('input', this)
```

If you need the DOM element and no the jQuery wrapped one, use

```
$('input', this).get(0)
```

[nextAll](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) doesn't look for a child but for a sibbling. That's why your code wasn't working.